# Adding numbers 1 to n with a loop

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, integer, break

So the code posted works and seems to give correct values. The only problem is that it prints every line in the loop instead of just the answer. How can I make it just print the answer instead of every line leading up to it?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CountLoop{
public static void main (String[] args){
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    int i = -1;
    int limit = 0;
    System.out.println("Please enter a number");
    String end1 = in.nextLine();
    int end = Integer.parseInt(end1);


    while (i < end){
        i++;
        limit = (i + limit);
        System.out.println("The sum of the numbers in between 0 and " + end + " is i = " + limit);

    }
}
```

}

I'm fine with using other types of loops as well, as I'll need to show an example with all the different types of loops being used anyway, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Move your `system.out.println` outside of your while loop

```
while (i < end){
    i++;
    limit = (i + limit);
}

System.out.println("The sum of the numbers in between 0 and " + end + " is i = " + limit);
```

Comment: Such a simple solution but an effective answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Or the modern version in Java 8:

```
int sum = IntStream.range(startInclusive,endExclusive).sum(); 

System.out.println("The sum of the numbers in between " + startInclusive +
                   " and " + (endExclusive -1) + " is sum = " + sum);
```

Renamed variables ;-)

> limit -> sum
>   0 -> startInclusive
>   end -> endExclusive - 1